# Sequelize & TS: How can I enforce the shape of the data input of a model's create method?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following sample code where I try to create an instance for a defined sequelize model using an interface to template out the body of the `model.create` call.

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:')

const Foo = sequelize.define('foo', {
  name: DataTypes.TEXT
})

interface FooAttributes {
  name: string
}

const myFooData: FooAttributes = { name: 'Joe' }

Foo.create(myFooData)
```

This code makes the IDE show an error claiming

```
Argument of type 'FooAttributes' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Optional<any, string>'.
  Type 'FooAttributes' is not assignable to type 'Omit<any, string>'.
    Index signature for type 'number' is missing in type 'FooAttributes'.
```

Is there a way to fix this? Without declaring the `myFooData` as a `FooAttributes`, the code works, but I am really looking for a way to force `myFooAttribute`'s shape at compile time. I tried looking into casting and even something like "erasing type" before the create stage (I don't think it's a thing), but nothing has worked. Any ideas?